# Converting a List of Lat/Long coordinates to a business name

Tags: python, google-maps-api-3

I havent used Python before but, am told this would be a good language to use for this process. I have a list of Lat/ Long coordinates that i need to convert into a business name. Any ideas where i might find documentation on how to complete this process?

Example:

Doc: LatLong.txt  (Has a list of lat / long seperated by columns)
I need to run that list against the Places API with a max radius of 30 and return any businesses (BusinessName, Addy, Phone, etc.) within that radius.

```
    from googleplaces import googleplaces

    YOUR_API_KEY = 'aa262fad30e663fca7c7a2be9354fe9984f0b5f2'

    google_places = googleplaces(YOUR_API_KEY)

    query_result = google_places.nearby_search(lat_lng=41.802893, -89.649930,radius=20000)

    for place in query_result.places:
        print (place.name)
        print (place.geo_location)
        print (place.reference)

        place.get_details()

        print (place.local_phone_number)
        print (place.international_phone_number)
        print (place.webite)
        print (place.url)
```

is what im playing around with..

Comment: are you able to share sample data ? or code you tried so far

Answer (score 1):

Google has some pretty good documentation for getting started:

https://developers.google.com/places/training/basic-place-search

Also this answer may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21924452/1393496

You should edit your question and include more detail, what have you tried? what worked? what didn't work?